# Why would a repository class call a static load method?

Tags: c#, repository-pattern, static-methods

I've been following Josh Smith's [excellent article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) on the MVVM pattern. In his example, he has a `CustomerRepository` that fetches data from a source:

```
public CustomerRepository(string customerDataFile)
{
    _customers = LoadCustomers(customerDataFile);
}
```

What I don't understand is the fact that he calls a static method, `LoadCustomers`, straight from his constructor:

```
static List<Customer> LoadCustomers(string customerDataFile)
{
    // In a real application, the data would come from an external source,
    // but for this demo let's keep things simple and use a resource file.
    using (Stream stream = GetResourceStream(customerDataFile))
    using (XmlReader xmlRdr = new XmlTextReader(stream))
        return
            (from customerElem in XDocument.Load(xmlRdr).Element("customers").Elements("customer")
             select Customer.CreateCustomer(
                (double)customerElem.Attribute("totalSales"),
                (string)customerElem.Attribute("firstName"),
                (string)customerElem.Attribute("lastName"),
                (bool)customerElem.Attribute("isCompany"),
                (string)customerElem.Attribute("email")
                 )).ToList();
}
```

Is this some kind of lazy-loading pattern, or is there some other specific reason a developer would do this?

Comment: Seems to me it exists to load test data.

Comment: Most likely you'll inject your repository into your ViewModel via dependency injection and at the right time use that to load the data. Like Michael said, it looks like a simple way to get some data for the example and doesn't necessarily reflect a snippet of  production code. A repository is often a singleton (via the container) as it will likely be thread-safe and there is no need for multiple instances so the container takes care of this. The static method call imitates this type of setup without the example needing to go into the details of dependency injection

Comment: @Charleh - So far, your comment makes the most sense to me. So the idea is to isolate the call to your data source as a static call, to avoid re-opening your connection if you have multiple instances of the repository. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this is specifically related to repositories. 
The method is static because it does not use any of the classes instance variables. There is a small performance improvement as you don't need to transfer the `this` reference over the stack.
As it is also private, you can safely mark it as static. For non-private methods, this is different, because if you use a static method from the outside, callers bind themselves to the concrete type that the static method defines. This makes the design less flexible and reduces testability. But as stated before, this is not an issue for a private method.

Comment: It is also functionally 'purer' -> free from the instance implementation and side effects that may arise from changing members and properties.

Comment: @Gusdor The method reads the contents of a file, thus is far from functionally pure, as it is non-deterministic, based on whether the file is there and what's in it. It could also result in an exception being thrown within the constructor.

Comment: @DavidArno I qualified my statement with 'purer', a relative term. I did not state that all side effects are abolished. There is only so much you can do with IO code after all. I should know better than to invoke the hole 'p' word on SO :P

Comment: @Markus Marking a private method as static should be reserved for deterministic functions with no side-effects. This isn't the case here

Comment: @David Arno: It is clear that constructors should be deterministic and should not fail. This sample violates that, but it's a sample that wants to demonstrate something different. Besides that, it is obvious deterministic functions are preferred over non-deterministic ones in many ways. But what is the reason that only deterministic private methods should be marked as static?

Answer (score 1):

(1) This is not Lazy loading.

(2)  If you see the comment within `LoadCustomers`, he clearly mentioned 'In a real application, the data would come from an external source,but for this demo let's keep things simple and use a resource file.'. This means, his intention was to show some data in UI rather the best way of bring data from some store to UI.

As mentioned via comments, in production quality code, we mostly follow some well define d pattern. Eg: Injecting repository object via dependency injection in your view model.

Comment: I agree, it's not lazy loading. In fact, were it not clearly marked as being a short-cut to keep the demo simple, *lazy coding* would be a better description. +1 for a good answer.

Comment: I do DI my repositories into my view-models, and I do so without any need for a static method to be called from the ctor. Sorry, but I don't see how this applies.